# How to iterate through parent element and its child elements and print element name xquery

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery

I want to iterate through all parent elements and child elements and print the element name out.

For example

```
<Asdf>
   <parentnode1>
        <childnode1>...</childnode1>
        <childnode2>...</childnode2>
    </parentnode1>
    <parentnode2>
        <childnode3>..</childnode3>
        <childnode4>..</childnode4>
    </parentnode2>
</Asdf>
```

Solution would be:

```
parentnode1 childnode1 childnode2 parentnode2 childnode3 childnode4
```

Now what I got so far:

```
let $a := fn:doc('asdf.xml')/Asdf/*

return 

for $z in $a
return $z/name()
  for $x in $a/*
  return $x/name()
```

What am I missing and why does this nested for loop not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this XQuery:

```
let $xdoc := doc('asdf.xml')/Asdf//*
return $xdoc/name()
```

Output is the string

> parentnode1 childnode1 childnode2 parentnode2 childnode3 childnode4

The above XQuery iterates over all child elements beginning at `/Asdf`.

Comment: What is the meaning of the '//' ?

Comment: `...//*` selects all elements at the same level (including itself) or a descendant level. It is a shortcut for the `descendant-or-self::` axis unless used at the beginning of an XPath expression (like `//*`).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your code isn't working is that you have a syntax error. In the `return` of your FLWOR statement, you have a sequence two things that you want to return.

So, you need to wrap that in parenthesis and add a comma, and I think you want to be referencing `$z` instead of `$a` in that for loop:

```
let $a := fn:doc('asdf.xml')/Asdf/*
return 
  for $z in $a
  return ($z/name(),
    for $x in $z/*
    return $x/name()
  )
```

Or a shorter version:

```
for $z in $a
return ($z/name(), $z/*/name())
```

@zx485 offers an easier way to achieve what you want. Even easier and shorter would be:

```
doc('asdf.xml')/Asdf//*/name()
```